# Checkout operation gives 403 response code JMeter

Tags: testing, jmeter, blazemeter

Hi there I am conducting a Stress test form JMeter. And I am doing a checkout operation for a shopping controller. But for most of checkout request are failing with 403 response code.
[image]

As you can see if I check the response data the page title says 503 but sample result says 403. So it is a bit confusing to me. And also for checkout operation I am using a module controller for login , so each time user do the checkout it should login. also I am using regular expression extractor to extract he csrf token for cart. So there should not be any authentication issues as the 403 error indicates. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Can you check if your service response manually when the load test is conducted? Apparently, the server is not able to handle the workload.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending the checkout requests in a production environment (like checkout on Amazon with PayPal), it is very normal that most of your requests are failing. Because it is some sort of protection to avoid frauding. You are sending lots of checkout request from the same ip address, so server starts to think that you are playing some sort of game there and decides to block you. In real-life performance tests; companies usually choose to mock this checkout endpoints to bypass the process or they use some test cards.